# How to correctly train and predict in Tensorflow 2?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am starting out with Tensorflow and trying to create a model for
a simple classification problem, but I can't get the input and output shapes matching correctly, and when I do, I can't call "predict" on the Keras model.

Let's say I want to recognise people based on fictive sizes/measurements.

The problem seems to be that I can't get the input and output shapes
matching correctly, and when I do, I can't call "predict" on the Keras model.
Here's what I have so far:

```py
#!python
import tensorflow as tf
print("TensorFlow version:", tf.__version__)
```

> TensorFlow version: 2.6.0

This is the limited dataset I want to train the model with (I know it needs
to be way bigger but first lets get this to compile)"

```py
# The names of people I want to identify
names = sorted({"Jack", "John", "Peter", "X"})

# The fictive sizes for each:
sizes = [
            [0.0, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.3], # Jack's sizes
            [0.2, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.5, 0.2], # John's sizes
            [0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.8, 0.9], # Peter's sizes
            [0.3, 0.9, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0, 0.8]  # X's sizes
]
```

Then I create a Keras Sequential model with 6 inputs, one for each size, and
4 outputs, one the probability for each name. A middle layer might be better
but I am trying to take out everything that could go wrong here:

```py
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(name="inputs",  units=len(sizes[0]), activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(name="outputs", units=len(names), activation='relu')
])
```

As fas as I understand this is called ["one-hot"](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy), where each of the outputs
generate a probability for that classification (name), and one will be "hot",
meaining closer to 1.0. So this is what I use to compile the model:

```py
model.compile(
        optimizer='adam',
        loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), # one-hot
        metrics=['accuracy']
)
```

Next up is training the model. As far as I understand, [`model.fit()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential#fit) can work with two arrays, X and Y, where X contains the input Tensors
and Y contains the expected output Tensors (so X[0] should yield Y[0], etc etc). This seemed to be the simplest setup, so I did:

```py
x = [tf.constant(s) for s in sizes] # Stack size Tensors for all names
y = [tf.constant(i) for i in [ # Stack categorization probabilities for each x -> y
       [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], # Jack's index
       [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], # John's index
       [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], # Peter's index
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]  # X's index
   ]]
```

When I call

```py
model.fit(x, y, epochs=5)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 6, 6, 6, 6
  y sizes: 4, 4, 4, 4
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
```

This strange, because my X and Y dataset are exactly the same size, and each Tensor
in X contains 6 values for the 6 inputs of the model, and each Tensor in Y contains
4 values for the outputs in the model.

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong here. I'd like to be able to train
the model, and then call `model.predict([0.0, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.3])` on it and
then get probabilities back indicating that this is likely Jack's measurements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the way you provide the inputs to `model.fit`. If x or y are lists of tensors/arrays, each element of the list is interpreted as a "separate input", i.e. observations of a different variable. In your case, the model gets 4 different variables, each with 6 observations, for `x`, and 4 different variables, each with 4 observations, for `y`, causing a mismatch.

The solution is to simply provide `x` and `y` as a tensor or array instead of a list of tensors:

`x = np.array(sizes)` (or `tf.constant` would be fine as well).

Same thing for `y`. Then, Keras will interpret the input as 4 observations of 6 variables for `x`, and 4 observations of 4 variables for `y`.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to train the model indeed, but then model.predict(sizes[0]) complains `Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 6 but received input with shape (None, 1)`.

Comment: Ah wait, that needs to be an array too, so `model.predict([sizes[0]])` did make a prediction (although being not correct, since my training set is so small). Thanks again!

Comment: When predicting on a single example, you still need to add a batch axis. I.e. your data needs to be in shape (1, 6) rather than (6,).